# look up missing values with PowerQuery

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

In the green table we fill in certain columns manually. Some columns (Fat, Protein) we want to get filled in from the blue table with PowerQuery.
All entries have a unique ID, which match between the green and blue table.

The green table has formulas (ID)  (is it ok with formulas in the table?)

Both tables grow during the day.

How can I get the missing values in the green table in column "Fat" and "Protein" from the blue table with PowerQuery?
I know only the basics in PowerQuery.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use a formula combining INDEX and MATCH functions to extract Fat and Protein. Or XLOOKUP if you have Excel 365.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio That would be easy but a lot of lookup formulas. This would be my last choice for different reasons. Is it possible with PowerQuery, not to complicated? Otherwise I might write a macro instead.

Comment: You can't enter data into the result table of a query in a reliable way. When the query refreshes, there's a risk the data you've entered will be in the wrong order, or overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to build a query to read in the blue table. Set that to **Load To / Only create connection** - so it doesnt create a new table.

Then back in your main query, add a **Merge Queries** step. Select the 2 id columns as the **matching columns**. Next expand the column added by the **Merge Queries** step to add the Fat and Protein columns to your query - there will be an Expand/Aggregate button in it's column header.

You might also want to add **Conditional Columns** to choose either your original columns or the ones from the **Merge Queries**, then remove the original columns.

Comment: I tried this already. So I ended up with 2 extra columns, but I don't want to delete my original columns, I just want to add values in the missing cells. Is that possible with PowerQuery?

Comment: Possible with custom code, but not the way to use the tool. Just rename columns and remove your original columns from the query.